# ckeditor not found after installing Filesystem component

Tags: symfony5

After installing the FileSystem component, my ckeditor bundle no longer works. The configuration file fos_ckeditor.yaml has been deleted along with the fosckeditor folder in the public folder.
So I reinstalled it again, but it doesn't work because there is still an error when I run the command "symfony console ckeditor:install".

It is important to notice that the "symfony req friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle" command has already been executed successfully.

Can anyone help me please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well you *should* be putting your code under version control, so you could checkout the configuration from a previous revision. But since you are asking, I guess you aren't. In that case, you could try reinstalling the ckeditor recipe `composer recipes:install friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle -v --force` or uninstalling the bundle completely and installing it again. However, we have no clue about what error might that be unless you give us more information.